# JavaScript Profiler in IE

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, profiling

Does anyone know a tool for Profiling JavaScript in IE?

List available:

- [IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) (Internet Explorer 8 only)
- [JavaScript Profiler](http://www.whitefrost.com/documents/html/technical/dhtml/jsprof.html)
- [YUI!](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/)

Answer (score 16):

Checkout http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/ the dynaTrace tool shown here is fantastic and works with IE7.

Comment: One note: looks like they now treat IE7 as a legacy browser, which means the free version no longer supports it.

Answer (score 10):

The Internet Explorer 8 beta (2) has a builtin Javascript profiler (in the developer toolbar).  It's worth playing with at least...

Answer (score 7):

[JavaScript Profiler](http://www.whitefrost.com/documents/html/technical/dhtml/jsprof.html) is a decent tool.

Answer (score 1):

YUI also provides a [profiler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/).

Answer (score 1):

[js-profiler](http://github.com/jeremi/js-profiler) also provide a profiler that is working in any browser and does not depend on any framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/) has a profiler.. but it does have a debugger and a console... so you can fake it...

Answer (score -7):

We use Firebugs console.log, console.time and console.timeEnd (I think) a lot.

Firebug also has a built in profiler.