# AJAX timing in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

Chrome has its developer tools that times ajax latency, firefox has firebug, but what do you do in IE? I would have thought firebug lite, but apparently it doesn't time ajax calls (at least not in IE6). How do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You use dynatrace ajax edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/). Not only will it give you what you are looking for, it will give you an incredible amount of performance profiling data including the browsers rendering time as well as page load times, execution time of javascript etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool to add to your toolbox

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own timing code.  Grab the start time before your Ajax call and get the end time from your callback function.

```
startTime = new Date().getTime();
//Make your Ajax call

function someCallback() {
  endTime = new Date().getTime();
}

alert((endTime - startTime) + " millis have elapsed.");
```

If you are using jQuery you can use the .ajaxSend and .ajaxComplete functions to register event handlers that can do the timings.