# ie7 ajax performance

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, internet-explorer-7

Are there any tools to measure performance (similar to FireBug > Net tab (FireBugLite = no net tab)) that work in IE7?

I am having some serious lag come up in loading up screens.  The issue seems to occur only within IE7.  The site uses quite a bit of javascript/ajax (jQuery).  I hear that IE7 has a poor JavaScript engine.  Is this true?  I mean, are there any known bugs, defined performance issues in jQuery API or otherwise "checkoutHowMuchIE7SucksComparedtoFF.Metrics.Ajax" dot com?

Comment: In general, code takes much longer to run on IE than it does other browsers. When you are dealing with arrays of data and looping, the differences in code execution gets multiplied by the number of times you are looping. This can cause significant delay differences.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie

Comment: if you are seeing lag only in IE odds are transport is good, the javascript engine would probably be at fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler should be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an idea of javascript engine performance across browsers (it lists IE8 not 7, but I believe 7&8 use the same javascript engine[someone correct me if I'm wrong])

http://sixrevisions.com/infographs/browser-performance/

Personally I use this technique to set up debugging in IE, without some code samples this is all I can suggest.

http://berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

[dynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) (Free) is very comprehensive JavaScript profiler.