# IE memory profilers for Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, profiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Profiler in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie)

We have a web application targeting Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9 that apparently has an IE memory leak. We can see that memory grows and performance deteriorates consistently over calls.

Is there any good Javascript profiler tool that may be used to find out objects staying in IE memory, like Ant profiler for .Net code.

We've tried IEJSLeaksDetector – it shows potential leaks but does not show memory allocation.
JavaScript Memory Validator of SoftwareVerify provides a good analysis but doesn't support IE.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

There is an [MSDN Doc for debugging memory leaks in IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/11/29/tools-for-detecting-memory-leaks.aspx)

And another good tool here : [IE Sieve](http://home.wanadoo.nl/jsrosman/)